# Setting Custom Browser Installation with Karma

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, browser, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm trying to run Karma tests on a custom installation of Firefox using these binaries: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.7.0esr/

I want to be able to run the Firefox binaries using Karma. I was wondering if there was a way to set the binary location for Firefox. I was hoping this could apply to pretty much any browser where you can choose to use their binaries at a custom location instead of default installation configurations. Currently here is what I have tried in my karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // For brevity, I only included the configuration for the browsers

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Firefox', 'FirefoxDeveloper', 'FirefoxNightly', 'IE', 'firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe'],

    customLaunchers: {
        FirefoxHeadlessLocal: {
            base: 'Firefox',
            flags: ['-headless'],
        },
        FireFoxHeadlessWin: {
            base: 'firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe',
            flags: ['-headless'],
        }
    }
  })
}
```

I currently have the firefox-sdk directory (which contains the Firefox binary) in the same level as my karma.conf.js file. I then tried to run this command to run my tests:

```
node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start --single-run --browsers FireFoxHeadlessWin karma.conf.js
```

Then I get this error:

```
19 08 2019 11:04:43.551:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "FireFoxHeadlessWin"!
  Error: No provider for "launcher:firefox-sdk/bin/firefox.exe". Can not use provider from the parent!
```

I am using Windows 7 currently to get this to work. I have considered using environment variables, but I want to to configure the paths locally as I would like to apply this to Linux because I am building this project on Windows and Linux. How do I get Karma to run my binaries at custom locations?